# Woocommerce - How to get Cart item details from Functions.php

Tags: woocommerce

I am adding a condition based surcharge on the cart page but can't work out how to retrieve the meta details for the cart items.

If I do the following I get the item name, quantity & cost.. but how do I get the extra meta info?

```
$items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();

    foreach($items as $item => $values) { 
        $_product = $values['data']->post; 
        echo "<b>".$_product->post_title.'</b>  <br> Quantity: '.$values['quantity'].'<br>'; 
        $price = get_post_meta($values['product_id'] , '_price', true);
        echo "  Price: ".$price."<br>";
    }
```

Is there some code like

```
 $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_items_details();
```

or maybe the answer lies deeper in the array.. ?
Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Are you adding your surcharge using this woocommerce function? Should be able to retrieve that info with $surcharge variable if so. https://docs.woothemes.com/document/add-a-surcharge-to-cart-and-checkout-uses-fees-api/.

Comment: yes sorry, i know how to add the surcharge, but i need to make it conditional on some of the information contained in the cart item's meta details, hence why i need to get the meta details